# how to generate JSON array for entire database tables from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I want this kind of JSON array,
database1 all tables

```
{
    {"table1":"[{"key11":"val11"},{"key12":"val12"},{"key13":"val13"}]"},
    {"table2":"[{"key21":"val21"},{"key22":"val22"},{"key23":"val23"}]"},
    {"table3":"[{"key31":"val31"},{"key32":"val32"},{"key33":"val33"}]"},
    {"table4":"[{"key41":"val41"},{"key42":"val42"},{"key43":"val43"}]"},
    {"table5":"[{"key51":"val51"},{"key52":"val52"},{"key53":"val53"}]"},
}
```

This bellow code is convert a single database table to JSON array, But i want entire database tables to JSON array

```
    $return_arr = array();
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");   
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['val2'] = $row['val1'];
        $row_array['val2'] = $row['val2'];
        $row_array['val3'] = $row['val3'];      
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }   
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

anyone help me please.

Comment: you mean whole database or particular table

Comment: yes whole database, i have code to particular table. I want to convert particular database and all tables in above format,  answer please.

Comment: you want Only tables name or whole entries from Tables also.

Comment: I want whole entries from Tables and all tables from a single database, answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all tables, you can use that query to get all tables.

```
select * from information_schema.tables
```

You still need to select all results inside the tables.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
$db='recipes';
$tables=$db->query('SHOW TABLES IN '.$db, O_ARRAY);
foreach($tables as $n=>$v){
    $table=$v['Tables_in_'.$db];
    $array=$db->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
    $data[$table]=$array;
}
echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($data);
```

that's going to be pretty memory intensive on large data! You might add some filters for unneeded fields, or database-specific fields that need to be skipped or the value translated to another place.

Comment: yes, i want this way of format, but can i run empty page is displaying, please can you simplify to WAMP server.

    `mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
 mysql_select_db('recipes');
 $db='recipes';
 $tables=mysql_query('SHOW TABLES IN '.$db);
 foreach($tables as $v)
 {
  echo $table=$v['Tables_in_'.$db];
  $array=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");
  $data[$table]=$array;
 }
 echo '<pre>';
 echo json_encode($data);`

  this code displaying output is null, please  just correct my code.

Comment: `mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('recipes');  
    $db='recipes';  
    $tables=mysql_query('SHOW TABLES IN '.$db);  
    foreach($tables as $v)  
    {  
        echo $table=$v['Tables_in_'.$db];  
        $array=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");  
        $data[$table]=$array;  
    }   
    echo '<pre>';  
    echo json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for above question change database name only all tables and table records are given in JSON array format.

```
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('database');
    $db='database'; 

    $return_arr = array();
    $return_arr1 = array();
    $return_arr2 = array(); 
    $return_arr3 = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES IN ".$db); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($return_arr,$row);
    }
    foreach($return_arr as $key => $value)
    {
        $table=$value['Tables_in_'.$db];
        $array1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");        
        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($array1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
        {
            array_push($return_arr3,$row1);
        }       
            $return_arr1[$table]=$return_arr3;
            unset($return_arr3);
            $return_arr3 =array();
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($return_arr1);
```

Comment: other than the db connection, this answer is basically the same as what I specified.  As you have 4 different arrays going, mine might take a bit less memory.  But as mine uses special db methods, it might be a toss-up